# How to use sum in where clause in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to execute this query:

```
Select Environment, SUM(Scores) as `Scores`,SUM(Clicks) as `Clicks` 
      from Example.table 
      where Scores > sum(Scores)
      group by Environment
```

But it throws the following error:

Aggregate function SUM not allowed in WHERE clause at [4:27]

whereas for the case of having:
`having Scores > sum(Scores)`
doesn't allow me to keep `Scores`. What is the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
Select Environment
       ,Scores
       ,SUM(Scores) as `Scores`
       ,SUM(Clicks) as `Clicks`  
       from TABLE 
      group by Environment, Scores
      HAVING (Scores > sum(Scores))
```

You need to include Score and group by that also (even if you don't need it).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the HAVING clause for comparison:

```
GROUP BY ...
  HAVING Scores > sum(Scores)
```

So your SQL will be something like:

```
Select Environment, SUM(Scores) as `Scores`,SUM(Clicks) as `Clicks` 
      from Example.table 
      group by Environment
      HAVING Scores > sum(Scores)
```

Comment: The HAVING clause only allows aggregation if GROUP BY or SELECT list aggregation is present at [1:37]